# Bootstrap layout - Adjust column width to its content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make the column's width equal to the size of text inside.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 container" >
    <span>Case Number</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
   background: #ddd;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f6wtznwd/3/)

It seems like the height is ok but not the width.
Thanks for help.

New Fiddle
[Cannot remove Gutters](https://jsfiddle.net/f6wtznwd/7/)

Comment: Try putting background color on span rather than the container: `.container span { background: #ddd; }`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    <div class="col-sm-2 container" >
        <span>Case Number</span>
    </div>
</div>

<style type=text/css>
    .container {
        background: #ddd;
        display: inline-block;
        padding:0px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: use in container padding:0px   

  .container {
       background: #ddd;
       display: inline-block;
      padding:0px;
    }

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Comment: Yes, that works but leads to another problem. A new Fiddle will show that now I cannot get rid of gutters.